# How to Create a URL to an Action in a Different Project in the Same Solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, mapping

I have two projects (created in MVC4) in one solution.One project is site and another project is site to manage employees.

[image]

The URLes are www.ambulangtrns.com and www.ambulangEmployee.com.

When I type this address www.ambulangtrns.com I have to execute the start action method in first project and when I type this URL  www.ambulangEmployee.com I want to execute action in second project. As you can see the two projects are in one solution.

So my question what is the best way to implement URL mapping(i,e. how access to projects in one solution using different URLs)?

Comment: When u will deploy these projects in IIS it will automatically map url to project.

Comment: @Mairaj,thanks for respond.so I do  not need to create a mapping insidesolution it made by IIS?

Comment: When u will host it IIS will ask you for name of website and path for it.

Comment: How do you want to reference the URLs? If they are two separate projects, then they do not share routing configuration or anything else. Why not put all of it into a single project? Perhaps use areas, as @New2ASPMVC suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use case for Areas.  Keeps it much cleaner and easier, IMHO.

Check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx